# Javascript major mode in Emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs

Which javascript major modes exist in Emacs, and what are their key-features ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

http://www.corybennett.org/download/javascript-mode.el

[Then again, maybe this what you are looking for?](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaScriptMode)

or [this?](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/)

People seem to prefer (at least given the highest rated answer):

**Updated:** http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/js2-mode-new-javascript-mode-for-emacs.html

Comment: The second link, to the [wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaScriptMode), is the most useful as it will be kept up to date. Currently: javascript* deprecated; espresso has been included in emacs as js-mode; js2-mode is the new cool thing.

Answer (score 15):

> js2-mode: a new JavaScript mode for Emacs
>
> ---
>
> This is part of a larger
>   project, in progress, to permit writing Emacs extensions in JavaScript
>   instead of Emacs-Lisp.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - M-x customize
> - Accurate syntax
>     highlighting
> - Indentation
> - Code folding
> - Comment and string filling
> - Syntax errors
> - Strict
>     warnings
> - jsdoc highlighting

http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/js2-mode-new-javascript-mode-for-emacs.html

With some documentation.

Comment: I'm currently using js2, and very pleased so far.

Answer (score 6):

I use Steve Yegge's [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/), and like it a lot.  It's quite configurable, its indentation ideas match mine, and most impressively it has a full JavaScript parser in it, so it can alert me to syntax errors as I type (indispensable for little things like trailing commas in property lists that bork IE).

Comment: re: `it can alert me to syntax errors as I type` : you can  do the same thing with Flymake and JSLint.

Answer (score 2):

Espresso mode is supposed to be quite good as well.

Comment: So far, since switching to espresso-mode from js2-mode a few days ago, I'm really liking it. I was finding js2-mode unusably slow, and obnoxious in its approach to indentation, to the point that I would often use java-mode or fundamental-mode instead.